# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|1-a^4\right|^x\sin\left(\frac{5}{|1-a^2|^x}\right)=$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Given $a^2>2$ then evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|1-a^4\right|^x\sin\left(\frac{5}{|1-a^2|^x}\right)$$

**My Attempt**

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|1-a^4\right|^x\sin\left(\frac{5}{|1-a^2|^x}\right)=5\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|1+a^2\right|^x\frac{\sin\left(\frac{5}{|1-a^2|^x}\right)}{\frac{5}{|1-a^2|^x}}=5\times \infty\times 1=\infty$$

So should the answer be infinity or undefined.

The given answer is undefined.

The answer could as well be infinity.

I also attempted by using series expansion for $\sin x$ and was getting infinity as answer.

Comment: Your attempt looks right. Infinity is not a number, so the limit is not a number and is thus undefined. Saying that the limit is $\infty$ just tells the reader in what way the limit doesn't exist.